gRPC communication between Ruby and C#
I have a gRPC server developed in C#.  The proto file has:
package xxx.common;
option csharp_namespace = "Xxx.ComCon";

service PeerController {
...
}

It's implementation in C#:
namespace Xxx.ComCon;

public partial class PeerControllerImpl : Peer { ... }

Now, I've copied the proto file to ruby and used protoc to generate the stubs:
require 'grpc'
require 'PeerController_pb'

module Xxx
  module Common
    module PeerController

And then I have the GrpcClient class:
class GrpcClient
    def initialize(peer)
      @stub = Xxx::Common::PeerController::Stub.new("#{peer.server.private_ip}:#{peer.port}", :this_channel_is_insecure)
    end
  
    def say_hello
      request = Xxx::Common::IdentifiedRequest.new(name: "RoR calling")
      response = @stub.say_hello(request)
      response.message
    end
  end

When executing the GrpcClient and get on the C# server the following error:
Service 'xxx.common.PeerController' is unimplemented.

It seems to me that there is a mismatch between the names implemented in C# "PeerControllerImpl" in the namespace "Xxx.ComCon" and the ruby caller namespace "xxx.common.PeerController".  Is this the case? How can this be resolved?
I was expecting the server to receive the request and return a message.  Here is the implementation of the SayHello method:
    public override Task<SuccessReply> SayHello(IdentifiedRequest request, ServerCallContext context)
    {
        var metadata = context.RequestHeaders;
        var clientId = metadata.GetValue("client-id");

        return Task.FromResult(new SuccessReply
        {
            Success = true,
            Message = $"Hello from PeerController to: " + request.Name,
        });
    }


option csharp_namespace and the equivalent in other languages is a mechanism to alias protobuf package names (xxx.common) to language-specific structures. It should not break the implementation as the generated code will retain the origin protobuf package name for the underlying messages.

A good debugging step would be to use a known-working gRPC client perhaps gRPCurl to invoke the server message to prove that the server (C#) is working correctly and eliminate ~50% of the problem.

I can call the server using a c# client without problem.  What strikes me as something wrong between Ruby and c# is the server error message:  'xxx.common.PeerController' that does not look like a c# class structure and the actual class in c# is PeerControllerImpl.

I will try gRPCurl and see what it reports

I found the error... thans DazWilkin... using gRPCurl.  Stupid mistake using the superclass and not the right class.

You're welcome! I'm pleased to hear it.
